# Formula to determine if an infinite line and a line segment intersect?

Tags: javascript, math, glsl, gpu

Given a point on a line and that line's slope how would one determine if the line, extending in each direction infinitely, intersects with a line segment `(x1,y1)`, `(x2,y2)` and, if so, the point at which the intersection occurs?

I found this, but I'm unsure if it's helpful here.
If someone wants to help me understand "rays", that's alright with me.
http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

I'm sorry that I'm an idiot.

Comment: So the line cannot be vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary point on the first line has parametric equation

```
dx = Cos(slope)
dy = Sin(Slope)
x = x0 + t * dx     (1)
y = y0 + t * dy
```

Line containing the second segment

```
dxx = x2 - x1
dyy = y2 - y1
x = x1 + u * dxx    (2)
y = y1 + u * dyy
```

Intersection exists if linear system

```
x0 + t * dx = x1 + u * dxx   (3)    
y0 + t * dy = y1 + u * dyy
```

has solution for unknowns `t` and `u`
and `u` lies in range `[0..1]`

Intersection point could be calculated with substitution of `u` found in the  equation pair (2)

Comment: Combined this answer with http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/44733/60691 to get the full resolution to my issue.

Comment: Actually, @Mbo can you provide any additional documentation for dx and dy as to why cos and sin on slope would give me those values. The answer seems to be mostly correct but Im seeing strangeness as slope approaches full verticality.

Comment: I assume that `slope` is angle between OX axis and line direction. If we want to define unit-length direction vector for line, then its components are cosine and sine `(dirx,diry) = (cos(slope), sin(slope))`  This approach works for any slope including vertical lines. What a strangeness did you seen?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't ask me to explain how exactly this is working, I've just extrapolated/rewritten it from some ancient code I've had laying around. (Actionscript 1)

some functions to build the objects for this example:

```
function point(x, y){ 
    return {x, y} 
}
function line(x0, y0, x1, y1){
  return {
    start: point(x0, y0), 
    end: point(x1, y1)
  } 
}
function ray(x, y, vx, vy){
  return {
    start: point(x, y), 
    vector: point(vx, vy)
  } 
}
function ray2(x, y, angle){
    var rad = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    return ray(x, y, Math.cos(rad), Math.sin(rad));
}
```

the intersection-code:

```
//returns the difference vector between two points (pointB - pointA)
function delta(a, b){ return point( b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y ) }
//kind of a 2D-version of the cross-product
function cp(a, b){ return a.y * b.x - a.x * b.y } 

function intersection(a, b){
    var d21 = a.vector || delta(a.start, a.end),
        d43 = b.vector || delta(b.start, b.end),
        d13 = delta(b.start, a.start),
        d = cp(d43, d21);

    //rays are paralell, no intersection possible
    if(!d) return null;
    //if(!d) return { a, b, position: null, hitsA: false, hitsB: false };

    var u = cp(d13, d21) / d,
        v = cp(d13, d43) / d;

    return {
        a, b,

        //position of the intersection
        position: point(
            a.start.x + d21.x * v,
            a.start.y + d21.y * v
        ),  
        //is position on lineA?
        hitsA: v >= 0 && v <= 1,
        //is position on lineB?
        hitsB: u >= 0 && u <= 1,

        timeTillIntersection: v,
    };
}
```

and an example:

```
var a = line(0, 0, 50, 50);

var b = line(0, 50, 50, 0);             //lines are crossing
console.log(intersection(a, b));

var c = line(100, 50, 150, 0);          //lines are not crossing
console.log(intersection(a, c));

var d = line(100, -1000, 100, 1000);    //intersection is only on d, not on a
console.log(intersection(a, d));

var e = ray(100, 50, -1, -1);           //paralell to a
console.log(intersection(a, e));
```

returns information about the intersection point, and wether it is on the passed lines/rays. Doesn't care wether you pass lines or rays.

about `timeTillIntersection`: if the first argument/ray represents a ball/bullet/whatever with current position and motion-vector, and the second argument represents a wall or so, then `v`, aka `timeTillIntersection` determines how much time it takes till this ball intersects/hits the wall (at the current conditions) in the same unit as used for the velocity of the ball. So you basically get some information for free.

Answer (score 0):

What you search is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). A line can be represented as a vector.

When you have 2 lines they will intersect at some point. Except in the case when they are parallel.

Parallel vectors **a,b** (both normalized) have a dot product of 1 (*dot(a,b) = 1*).

If you have the starting and end point of line **i**, then you can also construct the vector **i** easily.