# Find parametric line equation given a single point and slope?

Tags: javascript, math, glsl, gpu, intersection

In an [earlier answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687904/827441), I had asked how to find the intersection between a line segment defined by `(x1,y1),(x2,y2)` and an infinite line for which I had a single point on the line and its slope or angle in degrees.

One answer suggested using parametric line equations to find the intersection between two infinite lines and then resolving if the intersection point fell on the given line segment. I liked this technique and went with it.

Here is how the answer suggested converting my infinite line to parametric form:

```
dx = Cos(slope)
dy = Sin(Slope)
x = x0 + t * dx
y = y0 + t * dy
```

I'm wondering two things:

- Is this correct (specifically finding dx and dy using cos and sin respectively against slope)?
- Can someone provide documentation as to why this works if it does?

In my implementation (using `glsl`) I am seeing unexpected results as the slope of the line approaches full verticality.

Here is my `glsl` implementation as of now, based heavily off the already linked answer in addition to [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/44733/60691):

```
bool lineIntersection (out vec2 intersect, in vec2 point, in float slope, in vec2 pA, in vec2 pB) {
    // See: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/line-intersection-from-parametric-equation
    //      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687083/formula-to-determine-if-an-infinite-line-and-a-line-segment-intersect/41687904#41687904

    bool isIntersecting = false;

    float dx = cos(slope);
    float dy = sin(slope);

    float dxx = pB.x - pA.x;
    float dyy = pB.y - pA.y;

    float denominator = ((dxx * dy) - (dyy * dx));

    if (denominator == 0.0) {
        // Lines are parallel
        return isIntersecting;
    }

    float u = ((dx * (pA.y - point.y)) + (dy * (point.x - pA.x))) / denominator;

    if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
        // Intersection occured on line segment
        isIntersecting = true;
        intersect = pA + (u * vec2(dxx, dyy));
    }

    return isIntersecting;
}
```

Comment: Don't say "slope" when you mean "angle", they are different things. It sounds as if "angle" is what you mean.

Comment: What makes you think that? Ill be the first to admit Im basically a maths idiot but I do understand there is at least a relationship between slope and angle and given an angle one can determine a slope. What part of this question makes you think I mean an angle?

Comment: @bradleygriffith simply this `Cos(slope)` means your "slope" is `angle` but usual meaning of slope in 2D gfx is `dx,dy`. Also in GLSL the angle must be in radians not in degrees ...

Answer (score 0):

1. I assumed that `slope` is angle. Sometimes `slope` is understood as coefficient `k` of equation `y = a + k * x` - in this case `k` is tangent of angle. And such equation is not universal - it is not suitable for vertical lines.
2. Usually trigonometric function work with angle in radians, not degrees. If the first paragraph is not your issue, check for radians/degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Look:

> Is this correct (specifically finding dx and dy using cos and sin
>   respectively against slope)?

Think a line as a *vector* in cartesian plane, vector is constructed by *2 points* and for the sake of simplicity, imagine `(x1,y1)` as the origin/initial point which is *`(0,0)`* and the `(x2,y2)` as simply *`(x,y)`*

[image]

For the better look:

[image]

where:

- `|v|` is the magnitude (a scalar value) of the vector/line. This could be relative, in physic it can be force (2N, 3N, etc) or it can be just simply distance function `sqrt(x^2+y^2)`
- `Ø` is direction of the vector/line, it could be *degrees* or *radians*

If you see again it actually looks as triangle.

[image]

According to the trigonometry

- `cos Ø` = *adjacent side length /  hypotenuse length* = *b / a*
- `sin Ø` = *opposite length /  hypotenuse length* = *c / a*

Let's start with the *cos Ø* :

`cos Ø` = *adjacent side length / hypotenuse length* = *b /a*

*adjacent side length* is *x-axis length* thus:

`cos Ø` = *x-axis length* / *hypotenuse length*

hence

*x-axis length*  = *hypotenuse length* * `cos Ø`

if we about to apply this to *vector components* for the second picture above , you get :

- *x-axis length* = *hypotenuse length* * `cos Ø` = *`|v| cos Ø`*

if you apply the previous steps to *y-axis* instead, you'll get

- *y-axis length* = *hypotenuse length* * `sin Ø` = *`|v| sin Ø`*

Hence

`(x,y)` = (`x-axis length`, `y-axis length`) = ( `|v| cosØ`,`|v| sinØ`)

in your code its written as :

`(dx,dy)`= (`Cos`(slope), `Sin`(Slope))